# no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm havig problems with a form select. I'm mixing Bootstrap with Rails and I have a select that doesn´t work. The error says "no implicit conversion of String into Integer". I dont know why, beacuse I've been looking for in Stackoverflow andI've put the same in my code.

```
<%= form_for @control, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <%= f.label :level, class: "sr-only", for: "exampleInputEmail2" %>

          <%= f.number_field :level, class: "form-control", id: "exampleInputEmail2", placeholder: "Enter level" %>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group container">
        <div class="row datetimeselect">
            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>

                        <%= f.text_field :day, default: DateTime.current, :class => 'form-control' %>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>

        <select class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">

             <%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast', 1], ['post-breakfast', 2],['pre-lunch', 3]['post-lunch', 4]['afternoon', 5]['pre-dinner', 6]['post-dinner', 7]]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </select> 
      <%= f.submit "Save", type:"submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem in `options_for_select()` method, you have missing `,`:

```
# your code
<%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast', 1],
                                          ['post-breakfast', 2],
                                          ['pre-lunch', 3] <----- first missing comma
                                          ['post-lunch', 4] <----- again
                                          ['afternoon', 5] <----- again
                                          ['pre-dinner', 6] <----- again
                                          ['post-dinner', 7]]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

Just put `,` after all arrays, this should fix you problem.

***should be in one line!***

```
# valid syntax
<%= f.select :period, options_for_select([['pre-breakfast', 1],
                                          ['post-breakfast', 2],
                                          ['pre-lunch', 3],
                                          ['post-lunch', 4],
                                          ['afternoon', 5], 
                                          ['pre-dinner', 6],
                                          ['post-dinner', 7]]), {}, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: You were right, I had forgotten the ',' but the select doesn't show me any option. The select has no options and I don't know why.

Comment: @DavidDsr this is should be another question. =)

Comment: @DavidDsr accept my answer if i help you solve your problem. Happy coding!